# Abstract class implement a generic Interface Type

Tags: java, generics

This is a bit convoluted if you can follow along. I have this:

```
public interface Interface1<T> {
  void method1(T t);
}

public interface Interface2 { }

public interface Interface3 extends Interface1<Interface2> { }

abstract public class BaseClass<P extends Interface1> {
  P p;

  void method2() {
    p.method1(this);
  }
}

public class Concrete extends BaseClass<Interface3> implements Interface2 {
}
```

Interface2 and Interface3 will change with different implementations of BaseClass. The problem is in BaseClass method2 because `this` is not of type Interface2 which is what it expects in this specific case. It compiles and runs but it warns about an unchecked call.

I tried implementing the interface in the base class instead of the concrete class like this

```
abstract public class BaseClass<P extends Interface1, V> implements V 

public class Concrete extends BaseClass<Interface3, Interface2>
```

but Java doesn't like it. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I assume you want `BaseClass<P extends Interface1<Interface2>>` to match your specification.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with the first code. It compiles fine. Warnings, sure, but no errors, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I added the sentence to the question "It compiles and runs but it warns about an unchecked call." I want to make it fully type safe without the unchecked call.

Comment: Right now the compiler thinks it's passing an Object to p.method1.

Comment: Unchecked call is a cascade warning. The real warning is *"Interface1 is a raw type. References to generic type Interface1<T> should be parameterized"*. See comment by @ElliottFrisch for why.

Comment: Interface2 and Interface3 are going to change for different concrete implementations so I can't refer to them directly in BaseClass.

Comment: `p.method1(this)` means that `P` is expected to actually accept a `BaseClass`, so you need to bound it that way somehow. Either `P` is an `Interface1<? super BaseClass<P>>` or `BaseClass` implements some interface and you bound it with that. Otherwise, the design doesn't work and you have to delegate the implementation of `method2` downwards.

Comment: Please review my last answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve

```
interface Interface2 { }

interface Interface1<T> {
  void method1(T t);
}

interface Interface3 extends Interface1<Interface2> { }

abstract  class BaseClass<P extends Interface1<Interface2>> 
     implements Interface2{
  P p;

  void method2() {
    p.method1(this);
  }
}

class Concrete extends BaseClass<Interface3> implements Interface2 { }
```

It compile without any warning, the only change I made is:

```
abstract class BaseClass<P extends Interface1<Interface2>> implements Interface2
```

If you don't want to BaseClass implements directly Interface2 you can create a "marker":

```
interface InterfaceFOO {}   // <------------ Marker without methods

interface Interface2 extends InterfaceFOO{ } // <----- harmless extend

interface Interface1<T> {
   void method1(T t);
}

interface Interface3 extends Interface1<InterfaceFOO> { }

abstract  class BaseClass<P extends Interface1<InterfaceFOO>> 
     implements InterfaceFOO{
  P p;

  void method2() {
    p.method1(this);
  }
}

class Concrete extends BaseClass<Interface3> implements Interface2 { }
```

Comment: Thanks. But the idea is that Interface2 and Interface3 are going to change for each concrete implementation so they can't be referred to directly in the base class.

Comment: I did a change in the code, I created a marker interfaces InterfaceFOO , then BaseClass don't depend directly of Interface2

Comment: I did some changes in my answer